# In the fight between Jiraiya and Pain, why didn't Fukasaku and Shima's sound genjutsu affect Nagato?

Tags: naruto

In the fight between Jiraiya and Pain, why didn't Fukasaku and Shima's sound genjutsu affect Nagato?

I asked because:

- The Six Paths of Pain were dead and were only being controlled by Nagato wirelessly through the chakra rods.
- Shared vision and hearing with Nagato were demonstrated during fights and talks.
- I didn't see the genjutsu released, so the other Paths should never have been able to retaliate if Nagato was still in it.

(Or maybe it did, but I just missed a sequence)

Answer (score 1):

I think Nagato's awareness is divided between the Pains, so unless they were all affected by sound genjutsu, he would not be.